# watching ngModel inside my directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
<custom-input-container>
      <input ng-model="myModel1" />
</custom-input-container>

<custom-input-container>
      <select ng-model="myModel2" >
      </select>
</custom-input-container>
```

I want to do something like this(If possible, I want this directive to be usable on another app module by separating it in 'customInput.js')

```
myApp.directive('customInputContainer',function(){
     return{
        restrict: 'E',
        priority: 0, 
        link:function(scope,element,attr){
             scope.watch->//i want to watch the ngModel of
             the thing inside <custom-input-container>
             then do console.log('recipe was updated:'+thenewvalue);
        }
     }
});
```

Comment: Note: each input container only has 1 of either input/select/textarea on it

Comment: Are you aware of `transclude` and its implications?

Comment: sadly no...i'm very new to angularjs

Comment: That's ok. First you should understand this topic. basically, when adding element like `input` inside your own directive will erase this element. Look at this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude, if you'll need clarification on this topic, let us know.

Comment: so How do I do it without using ngTransclude?, i want my directive to be as simple as angularmaterial's <md-input-container>

Comment: If you want it to be dinamic, meaning that the input can be whatever you choose, I can only think of transcluding. You can, of course, create a directive for each input type with its specific handling.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113424/discussion-between-makoto-lavan-and-arans).

Comment: so if I skip the dynamic part of it and only include <input>..can it be done without using transclude?

Comment: It can be done without transclude, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I got it working like this

```
myApp.directive('customInputContainer',function(){
     return{
        restrict: 'E',
        priority: 0, 
        link:function(scope,element,attr){
             var modelToWatch = element.find('input','select').attr('ng-model');
             scope.$watch(modelToWatch,function(newVal,oldVal){
                  console.log('recipe updated:'+newVal);
             });
        }
     }
});
```

Now the only problem remaning is how to make custom-input-container injectable to other projects without modifying my customInput.js

Answer (score 0):

To watch an `ng-model` variable inside an element directive, add an attribute with the name of the desired variable.

```
  <custom-input-container recipe='myModel1'>
      <input ng-model="myModel1" />
  </custom-input-container>
  <br />
  <custom-input-container recipe='myModel2'>
      Select
      <select ng-model="myModel2"  
              ng-options="name for name in [1,2,3]">
      </select>
  </custom-input-container>
```

Then in the directive, add a watcher.

```
app.directive('customInputContainer',function(){
     return{
        restrict: 'E',
        link:function(scope,element,attr){
             scope.$watch(attr.recipe, function(value) {
                 console.log('recipe was updated: ', value);
             })
        }
     }
});
```

The above directive uses the `recipe` attribute to determine the variable to watch.

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5qy5yqrr/)